# How does one change only the frequency of an alternating current?

Tags: power-electronics, component-selection

Suppose standard voltage, current, and frequency AC power is readily available for a project that requires the available standard voltage and current, but also requires an arbitrary number of cycles per second not equal to the number of cycles per second available.

What components affect the frequency of alternating current?

*Eg:*
*Provided: 60Hz 120v 1a*
*(Converter Goes Here)*
*Required: 10Hz 120v 1a*

What would such a converter consist of?